# How to get entire image scanned and not only the QR code in flutter?

Tags: flutter, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner, scanning

The user scans QR code and the image is displayed in another screen. I do not want to display only the QR code but also the entire image i.e the content outside the QR code as well like a normal image.

I am using BarcodeScanner for scanning the QR code as below,

```
barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
```

This gives only the QR code (link / url) and I also know to generate the QR code from this URL. But I do not know how to save the entire image and not only the QR code.

Comment: you can mix `ImagePicker` with `BarcodeScanner`. take a photo and scanning QR by photo or take force photo before Future return url from QR

Comment: I have done it. But the issue is when I use camera for capturing the image, only if the image has QR code, it should recognise and go back to previous screen automatically. This is not possible in normal camera pic...